# "Error: Mysql driver is NOT enabled" (editing suphp.conf, changing php binary)

Tags: php, mysql, apache, cakephp

With this binary (**PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.26**) :

```
application/x-httpd-suphp="php:/usr/bin/php-cgi
```

I have no problem.

But when I try to use this one which is an higher version of php (**PHP 5.5.38**) :

```
application/x-httpd-suphp="php:/usr/local/bin/php-cgi"
```

I get a problem on my Cakephp 2.x application :

> Error: A Database connection using "Mysql" was missing or unable to
>   connect.   The database server returned this error: Selected driver is
>   not enabled
>
> Error: Mysql driver is NOT enabled
>
> Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create
>   app/View/Errors/missing_connection.ctp
>
> Stack Trace
>
> CORE/Cake/Model/ConnectionManager.php line 105 →
>   DboSource->__construct(array) CORE/Cake/Model/Model.php line 3626 →
>   ConnectionManager::getDataSource(string) CORE/Cake/Model/Model.php
>   line 1155 → Model->setDataSource(string) CORE/Cake/Model/Model.php
>   line 3653 → Model->setSource(string) CORE/Cake/Model/Model.php line
>   3031 → Model->getDataSource() CORE/Cake/Model/Model.php line 3003 →
>   Model->_readDataSource(string, array) APP/Controller/AppController.php
>   line 87 → Model->find(string, array) APP/Controller/HomeController.php
>   line 10 → AppController->beforeFilter() [internal function] →
>   HomeController->beforeFilter(CakeEvent)
>   CORE/Cake/Event/CakeEventManager.php line 243 → call_user_func(array,
>   CakeEvent) CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php line 676 →
>   CakeEventManager->dispatch(CakeEvent) CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php
>   line 189 → Controller->startupProcess()
>   CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 167 →
>   Dispatcher->_invoke(HomeController, CakeRequest) APP/webroot/index.php
>   line 115 → Dispatcher->dispatch(CakeRequest, CakeResponse)

Does someone have an idea to resolve this ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check in the php.ini of your PHP5.5 installation weather the MySQL driver is loaded:

```
extension=mysqli.so
extension=mysql.so
extension=pdo_mysql.so
```

However, the [original MySQL extension is in PHP5.5 deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php), and will generate E_DEPRECATED errors when connecting to a database. Instead, use the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extensions.

Comment: Check it like this: <?php print_r(get_loaded_extensions());

Comment: You're right, the mysql extensions are loaded in the 5.3 but not in the 5.5.

When I try to add that extension=mysql.so on the 5.5 php.ini file

I get this error on the script :

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/mysql.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Comment: I tried to put the mysql.so from the php5.3 there but php doesn't lemme trick like this : "Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    compiled with module API=20121212
These options need to match"

Comment: Have you compiled PHP yourself or how did you install PHP5.5?

Comment: I compiled php-5.5.38 because on that old ubuntu server if I apt-get php5 it will be an old version.

I compiled php-5.5.38 again with make install. I don't understand why mysql is not included in the extensions.

Comment: It's alright I solved it by specifying the extensions I want to include like "./configure --with-mysql --with-mysqli --with-pdo-mysql" !

Comment: Exactly, I guess that. This is why I had asked if you have compiled it yourself. :)

Comment: Your are welcome. Please feel free to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).